# Convert String in Text File to Math furmul

Tags: c#, file, search

how to Convert String in Text File to Math formula in c#
look  i have  Several formula in my text file

i want search in my file and show Result(s)[formula]

like real math formula with no ^ char  or pow and etc...
thank you

Comment: What does the formula look like? Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes  i use richtextbox and import furmula in rtf file but can sratch in rtf file and  i try index in text file but can show result cant show aprat of rft file

Comment: I googled and found this link that has a library to help you https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/255573/How-to-convert-string-formula-to-a-mathematical-fo

Comment: tnx Mr.Najiullah   but i thnik this isent work for me

Comment: i want   something like  library  for convert string to furmula ...

Comment: i want   something like  library  for convert string to furmula ...

Comment: Here's the library that was recommended in the previous link I posted http://flee.codeplex.com